# xcode segmentedcontrol title - How to style the title

Tags: xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

Please see the attached image. I'm trying to change the color on the segmented control title, and I cannot find the appropriate attribute. If this is in the Apple docs, I'd be happy to be shown where...

Can anyone please enlighten me..

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 5.0 introduced some appearance customization options for `UISegmentedControl`.  I think the method you'd be most interested in is:

```
- (void)setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes forState:(UIControlState)state
```

> **Discussion**
> The attributes dictionary can specify the font, text color, text shadow color, and text shadow offset for the title in the text attributes dictionary, using the keys in NSString UIKit Additions Reference.

## Update

If you're creating your UISegmentedControl programmatically, you can just go ahead and call this method right after you create it.  If you're loading from a nib, you'll have to set it as an outlet and call this method in your `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad` method.

Now, your "Please tap the appropriate button" text is in the navigation prompt?  I'm not sure if you can modify the look of that.  Perhaps you could do some trickery...

- Set `self.navigationItem.prompt = @" ";` so it's technically set but doesn't have anything to display.
- Make a `UIView`, add your `UISegmentedControl` to that, as well as a `UILabel` that you style the way you want with the `frame.origin.y = -20.0` or so.  Then, set that view to `self.navigationItem.titleView`.  Make sure you set `clipsToBounds = NO` and `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`.

That way, it should display the segmented control with your custom label over it, theoretically at least.  Let me know how this turns out.

Comment: Thanks Joe, how do I invoke the method. It isn't firing. This is the code I'm using:

Comment: - (void)setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes forState:(UIControlState)state {
 NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
 [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
   [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
   [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
   [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:11.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
   nil] 
             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

Comment: Joe, I found that the code will change the segmented array elements, but it cannot change the navigation item.prompt. Unless someone post an alternative solution, I will likely take that bit out. It's not too useful anyway.. I do appreciate the code tip that you gave me, so I will mark this as solved.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comments until just a few minutes ago.  I've updated my answer with something that will hopefully help.  Sometimes tweaking the look of the UI becomes way more complicated than it should.

Comment: Thanks again Joe. I'll try that technique this morning.. David